# I'm using flutter_webview_plugin and there is a web page in which a button implemented with the window.print function, i need to make that functional

Tags: flutter, function, printing

I'm using flutter_webview_plugin in my flutter application, where I've set some URL to display in the app. The website which I'm using has a button to print the current page. That button is wrapped with this javascript

```
function myPrint(){
      window.print();
   }
```

That function is properly working on the PC and Mobile browsers perfectly, but how could I make that work on the flutter app too?

Answer (score 0):

use this plugin it's so good and has a lot of events, methods, and options
[InAppWebView](https://inappwebview.dev/docs/in-app-webview/basic-usage)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).